# List total count of record that has been searched previously in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am making one search engine application in PHP and MySQL database. I want one report which shows a total number of count of records that has been searched previously. Suppose I have 100 rows in my database and around 45 records are searched so I want 45 as result on my dashboard. How can I perform this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Rather a broad question but did you find and tried any of the aggregate mysql functions, or did you not know what to look for? You also need to use UPDATE in order to accomplish what you're wanting to do here.

Comment: Not getting your answer.... Kindly explain in brief with example if it is possible...

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to mysql and php  but you might be able to use something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE NOT row_data = 'search_term'. That's based on my interpretation of the question of course. I'm assuming you will search for some data in the records until it's found. Is that right?

Comment: You have the general idea. However, this goes further than just counting rows. Read the question again, you may have missed something.

Comment: I've read it again so many times. Still not sure exactly what's being asked or what I've missed. The only thing I could think of is maybe a query to find distinct values. Then count the rows from the result? I feel I'm still way off so would love some guidance